# Animate span on data change in Vue js

Tags: javascript, css-animations, vuejs2

I want to animate (fade in/out) following div when `line` changes:

```
<div v-text="line"></div>
```

Here is `js` code which changes `line` data on certain interval.

```
setInterval(()=> {
   this.line = this.randomString();
}, 10000);
```

I know how to do on hide/show using `v-if`. But how to animate span or div using Vue.js on data change?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without commenting.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    button(@click="handleSomeChange") Test Animation

    transition(name="fade")
      div(v-if="showContent")
        h4 Voila! It works ;)
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showContent: true,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleSomeChange() {
      this.showContent = false;

      // writer you data change logic here...

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showContent = true;
      }, 100);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
  }

  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```